# Enquiry on Javascript Closure

Tags: javascript

I came across a JS Function in Effective Javascript book by David Herman. I have copied the code below. I just want to know how Updated Value of "i" is accissible in hasNext function, when "i" is incremented only in next function.

**Javascript**

```
function values() {
    var i = 0, n = arguments.length; a = arguments; 
    return {
        hasNext: function() { 
            alert(i);
            return i < n;
        },
        next: function() {
            if (i >= n) {
                throw new Error("end of iteration");
            }
            return a[i++];
        }
    };
}

var it = values(1, 4, 1, 4, 2);
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/G42Ev/

Answer (score 1):

`i` is **declared** on line 2 (via `var`). It is inside `values` and thus scoped to `values`.

Both `next` and `hasNext` are declared (by virtue of being function expressions) inside `values` (and don't mask `i` by declaring another `i` in a narrower scope) so have any access to any variables scoped to it.

Answer (score 1):

When `i` is accessed by either `next` or `hasNext`, they don't find an `i` in their own closure, so they look up one closure and find an `i` in the closure of `values` (the closure in which `var i` happens)

This means changes to and reads from `i` in those two functions both *share* the same `i`